# Deprecated .csrf() and .requiresChannel() methods after Spring Boot v3 migration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I tried to migrate an older project to the newest version of Spring Boot a.k.a 3.1.2, as we speak. However, the .csrf() and .requiresChannel() methods of the below piece of code no longer work because of deprecations.

I can't find the methods that have replaced them. Can you help?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig {

    private final ApplicationUserService applicationUserService;

    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public ApplicationSecurityConfig(
            ApplicationUserService applicationUserService,
            BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.applicationUserService = applicationUserService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .requiresChannel()
                    .antMatchers("/actuator/**")
                    .requiresInsecure()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(
                            "/api/v*/registration/**",
                            "/register*",
                            "/login",
                            "/actuator/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .usernameParameter("email")
                    .permitAll()
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/",true)
                    .failureUrl("/login-error")
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID","Idea-2e8e7cee")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider =
                new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(applicationUserService);
        return provider;
    }
}
```

Comment: Deprecation generally does not mean that the method stops working, just that you switch to their replacement (generally documented in the javadoc), because they might be removed in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The implementation of `filterChain` will have next one body, but for more details and more information why so. you must have a look to [Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html) it is about **Configuration** steps also about overall changes you can find out here [Servlet Migration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/index.html)

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    http.requiresChannel(c -> c.requestMatchers("/actuator/**").requiresInsecure());
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(request -> {
              request.requestMatchers(
              "/api/v*/registration/**",
              "/register*",
              "/login",
              "/actuator/**").permitAll();
              request.anyRequest().authenticated();
        });
    http.formLogin(fL -> fL.loginPage("/login")
            .usernameParameter("email").permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
            .failureUrl("/login-error"));
    http.logout(logOut -> logOut.logoutUrl("/logout")
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID","Idea-2e8e7cee")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login"))

    return http.build();
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

The `HttpSecurity` methods have been changed to take Customizers which can be implemented as lambdas. I had to deal with this with `csrf()` and the equivalent code is:

```
.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
```

I have not had to do it with `requiresChannel()` but I believe the equivalent code would be:

```
.requiresChannel(req -> req.requestMatchers("/actuator/**").requiresInsecure())
```

You will need to make similar changes to the other calls on `http`.

Answer (score 1):

For `.csrf()` you can use:

```java
.csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable());
```

[Documentation Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#csrf())

And for `requiresChannel()` you can use:

```java
.requiresChannel(req -> req.requestMatchers("/actuator/**").requiresInsecure())
```

[Documentation Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#requiresChannel())

Answer (score 0):

For `.csrf()` you also can use this method call:

```
   http.csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable);
```